# Word to describe a manager who's loyalties lie with superiors rather than subordinates

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe the managerial style of a manager who's loyalties and demeanor are allied to this person's superiors rather than with this person's subordinates.

One word that describes this would be 'Corporate' but that feels like it has negative connotations and I'm looking for a more netural sounding word.

Comment: Toady? Company man? Gobshite?  One of those may suit.

Comment: @Aethelbald ... no the OP said he did not want negative connotations.

Comment: @GEdgar, lighten up.  The middle one nails it.

Comment: Whose, not who's. who's = who is.

Comment: The Danish have an expression for this, "Kissing up and kicking down."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**company man**. [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/company+man)

n.
A man whose primary allegiance is to his employer.